# How to find note with hashtag inside

Tags: ios, evernote

Trying to figue out how to do a search using evernote API to get note with hashtag.
Right now whenever I type # it just return everything.

If I want to search for #something it never take the # in consideration resulting all notes with something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [findNotesMetada](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) API and specify words using the [NoteFilter](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter). Alternatively you can use tags when you create a [Note](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Types.html#Struct_Note).

Comment: I tested but note without hashtag will show up as well. if I put the word "#something" note with something and #something will both show up.

Comment: There is a reason I want to use hashtag instead of tag

Comment: Thats expected search behavior. This is because if you search for "something" most users want "#something" to show up as well. You can try the same in something like GMail and you will see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the API and it only take care of underscore "_". Seems like other are not supported in text query.